# C# - явное преобразование

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть Класс WebRequest, а есть FtpWebRequest.

Объявление экземпляра `FtpWebRequest request = new (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create();`

Прочитал книгу Троллсена по C# и видел такой способ только в примере **явной реализации интерфейсов** `(Interface)Class.Method`, когда в классе реализовано множество методов с одним именем но от разных интерфейсов, тогда для вызова конкретно унаследованого метода используется приведение к интерфейсу, однако в случае с WebRequest конструкция выглядит как (Class)Class.Method.

Хотелось бы узнать почему, для чего и как это работает?

Comment: в данном случае абсолютно для того же: приведение объекта к типу

Comment: Ситуация такая, что есть абстракция (WebRequest) которая реализует метод (Create) и результат его надо привести к конечному виду, но зачем такие сложности? Почему у класса потомка нельзя просто реализовать свой метод create через override?

Comment: @BlackOverlord на мой взгляд, WebRequest.Create - это одна из дырок в дизайне .NET. Т.е. была попытка сделать общий подход для работы с разными протоколами, но не взлетело, т.к. протоколы слишком отличаются и на практике постоянно приходится кастовать.

Comment: @BlackOverlord, потому что это статический меотд, а их нельзя перегружать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `WebRequest.Create` в зависимости от фактического протокола может возвращать и `HttpWebRequest`, и `FtpWebRequest`, и другие типы. Причём выяснять, какой именно тип нужен, приходится во время выполнения: ведь вы по строке или `Uri` не можете на этапе компиляции сказать, какой конкретно тип адреса в ней будет! Поэтому он возвращает «общий», базовый тип.

Вот если бы гипотетически в .NET были типы, скажем, `HttpUri` и `FtpUri`, то основываясь на их типе можно было бы создать две перегрузки функции `Create`, возвращающих нужный тип. (Но это вызвало бы свой набор проблем: в большинстве случаев программистам не хочется точно знать, какой конкретно тип адреса у вас есть, и они всё равно пользовались бы общим типом `Uri` или просто строкой.)

Comment: а почему не сделали чтобы функции из базового класса работали? наследование полиморфизм, все дела?

Comment: @Grundy: Но как? Какой тип должен возвращать `WebRequest.Create(Uri)`?

Comment: какой-нибудь базовый `webrequest` например, ну вернее да нужный тип обернутый в базовый. Понял теперь, что нельзя определить какой тип создавать :)

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду общий, то так и происходит, как вы описали. С возвращённым WebRequest'ом можно работать и так. Просто в нём не будут доступны ftp-специфические фишки.

Comment: А какие например?

Comment: Кажется понял суть, спасибо)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, я открыл https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx и смотрю свойства, около которых не написано «Inherited from WebRequest». Вижу, например, `ReadWriteTimeout` и `RenameTo`.

Comment: @BlackOverlord: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD, да, что-то с этим они не докрутили, но по идее это все можно было в какие-нибудь сеттинги запихнуть а сам класс запроса оставить

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, тогда, если я правильно вас понял, эти настройки будут нетипизированы, и при обращении вам нужно будет проверять наличие свойства и его тип. То есть из C# получится JavaScript. И это всё чтобы сэкономить один несчастный каст?

Comment: @VladD, это да :):):) я тоже не докрутил :):):) но наверняка как-то можно было сделать и без кастов и с типизацией :)

Comment: @Grundy: Они пока не придумали, но процесс идёт :)